# Use data frame to create multiple excels/csv

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am new to python programming, and I am trying to think how to create multiple excels from a data frame. I have a Pandas data frame as shown below,

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID | Claimed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MHI000000038710 | 100039 | Yes |
| MHI000000038715 | 100039 | No |
| MHI000000038711 | 100043 | Yes |
| MHI000000038712 | 100043 | No |

For every Voucher ID, I am trying to create excels for every Invoice No. from data frame where Claimed = Yes. But every excel should contain all the rows for same Voucher ID irrespective of Claimed is Yes/No. For the above example, the output would be 2 excels named after each Invoice No. where Claimed = Yes(i.e., MHI000000038710and MHI000000038711).

And each excel should contains rows grouped by Voucher ID

Excel 1 (`MHI000000038710.xlsx`): -

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID | Claimed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MHI000000038710 | 100039 | Yes |
| MHI000000038715 | 100039 | No |

Excel 2 (`MHI000000038711.xlsx`): -

| Invoice No. | Voucher ID | Claimed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MHI000000038711 | 100043 | Yes |
| MHI000000038712 | 100043 | No |

The script that I have currently is creating excel for all the invoices. I am not able to figure out how not create invoices where Claimed = No but still have all the rows in the invoices created for Claimed = Yes

```
for myid in df['Voucher ID'].unique():
    df_singleID = df[df['Voucher ID']==myid]
    for myinvoice in df_singleID['Invoice No'].unique():
        df_singleID.to_excel(output+"\\"+str(myinvoice)+'.xlsx',index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ?

```
for _, g in df.groupby("Voucher ID"):
    filename = g.loc[g["Claimed"].eq("Yes"), "Invoice No."].iloc[0]
    g.to_excel(f"{filename}.xlsx", index=False)
```

*NB: The filename is calculated with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).*

Comment: @Timelsess, thanks for help. The script works fine with smaller dataset. When I try to run on bigger dataset it throws error. IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: You're welcome but this is not due to the size of your dataset rather than its content.  It seems that on _at least_ one of the groups (`Voucher ID`), there is no (`Invoice No.`) with (`Claimed`) tagged as "Yes". No one can control that except you ;)

Comment: thanks again. Yes, you were correct. It is working now. But the script is not creating excels for invoices (for a Voucher ID) which has Yes and are after an invoice with No, for e.g., Voucher ID 10112 has 3 invoices MH1011, MH1012 and MH1013. The Claimed status for MH1011 and MH1013 is Yes while for MH1012 is No. So, the script is creating excel only for MH1011 and not for MH1013.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get the index error using .query() and list comps:

```
import pandas as pd


path = "path/to/file"
invoices = df.query("Claimed.eq('Yes')")["Invoice No."].tolist()
dfs = [x.reset_index(drop=True) for _, x in df.groupby("Voucher ID")]

[df.to_excel(f"{path}/{file_name}.xlsx", index=False) for file_name, df in dict(zip(invoices, dfs)).items()]
```

Comment: @ Jason Baker, thanks for solution. Looks like there is a syntax problem at "invoices = df.query("Claimed.eq('Yes')")["Invoice No."].tolist()" getting an error "UndefinedVariableError: name 'Claimed' is not defined"

Comment: It's your column name so it should exist.